# Cleaning up a Git branch of unneeded commits and extraneous branches

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

[image: repo tree]

How can I get rid of everything and only be left with the last commit at the bottom? Everything after `a28fe12` is expendable.

I've tried using `git rebase` and `git reset HEAD~n` as I've done hundreds of times but it seems like something got messed up on the way and I got myself into a rut, and I get to a "clean" state with the master branch.

`git reset --hard cd3a8cb` produces the following result:

[image: repo tree]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done it locally. Now you need to push it out to remote repositories.

`origin/master` and `jvk-github/master` are showing you where the master branch is on the remote repositories `origin` and `master` *the last time you looked*. If you `git fetch origin` and `git fetch jvk-github` you will get an updated view.

You need to push your update to these remotes. `git push --force-with-lease origin` and `git push --force-with-lease jvk-github`. [`--force-with-lease` is a safer `--force`](https://blog.developer.atlassian.com/force-with-lease/).

However, this means losing all the other commits, including adding screenshots and removing redundant dependencies. Only `origin/master` appears to have messed up, possibly as a result of some combination of rebasing and pulling.

`jvk-github/master` seems fine. I'd suggest instead moving your master to `jvk-github/master` and pushing that to `origin`.

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard jvk-github/master
git push --force-with-lease origin master
```

Finally, to prevent this sort of issue, I recommend pulling with rebase. By default `git pull` is a `git fetch` plus a `git merge`. This can result in duplication if a branch has been rebased after pushing, as appears to have happened with `origin/master`.

Instead, update with `git pull --rebase`. Your local work will be rebased on top of the remote work. I recommend making this the default by setting `pull.rebase = merges`.

Answer (score -1):

`git reset --hard cd3a8cb` will reset your branch to the first commit. Everything above that will be discarded.

Comment: That still leaves the red and orange branches floating